# Website doesn't work after upgrade to PHP 5.5

Tags: php, php-5.5

I had to upgrade PHP from 5.3 to 5.5 on my server due to my provider. My website then stopped working. I went back to PHP 5.3 for now. Locally I am testing with MAMP and PHP 5.5 and have the same issue.

The situation:

1. I have an index.php file that does `include_once("php/functions.php")`. It works as it returns true.
2. About the end of the file index.php I have a php section as below:

   ```
   <?php
       echo("<p>(1) before function call</p>");
       echo outputFooter();
       echo("<p>(4) after function call</p>");
   ?>
   ```
3. The PHP function in the file php/function.php is as follows:

   ```
   function outputFooter() {
      echo("<p>(2) In the function</p>");
      return("<p>(3) In the outputFooter function</p>");
   }
   ```
4. The output is:

   > (1) before function call

So obviously the PHP function is not called at all! Any ideas what in PHP 5.5 is causing this issue?

Comment: Do any of the functions in functions.php work?

Comment: Good question!No. No function works at all!

Comment: Hmm, this makes me wonder if it's being included properly. Put a couple of echo's at different points, see if you can narrow down where it's breaking

Comment: OK, I will try and get back again...

Comment: I am sorry! I see now that include_once does not work! It returns false! I checked the path and the access rights (-rw-r--r--) of the functions.php. All look OK.

Comment: What about e**X**ecute rights? Also the way you're echo-ing the `outputFooter()` function could be problemous.

Comment: I added executable rights to the file but it still doesn't work!

Comment: I am using htmlentities(getcwd()) that shows the path perfectly. After it If am using an if (file_exists(...)) to check whether the file can be found by PHP, but here the program stops working!

Comment: file_exists("php/function.php") returns TRUE. But include_once("php/functions.php") crashes! How is this possible???

Comment: @user3704589 why aren't you reading your (apache) error logs?

Comment: You need to read the version notes and [migration guides](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/migration54.php) between versions. It may be drudgery, but this is part of programming.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

My guess is that there is a syntax error or fatal runtime error that happens on load in the included file.

Comment: This should have been a comment. While it might _lead_ to an answer it isn't itself answering the (unanswerable/unclear) question.

Comment: @ jtmanteo: thank you so much for the advice. It helped me to find the reason of the problem. It was in the php file I was trying to open. I had a procedure call passing references to it like &$some_var. It seems so as though it worked with PHP 5.3 but not with PHP 5.5! So include_once did find the php file, but it crashed during reading it. By your advice I could get the appropriate error message. So thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

@ jtmanteo: thank you so much for the advice. It helped me to find the reason of the problem. It was in the php file I was trying to open. I had a procedure call passing references to it like &$some_var. It seems so as though it worked with PHP 5.3 but not with PHP 5.5! So include_once did find the php file, but it crashed during reading it. By your advice I could get the appropriate error message. So thanks again!!

The problem is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command line, you can run:

```
php -l *
```

across the directories where you host your files. That will use the inbuilt PHP engine to lint the files for any syntax errors that would cause a white screen, although it will not find run time errors. You can also run:

```
php *
```

if your files are self contained, but that can become problematic if your scripts are called by a framework at run time.